# How to convert an org-table to JSON?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, json

Here is a minimal example of an `org-table`:

```
#+NAME: radar
|----------+------|
| Variable |  Val |
|----------+------|
| Red      | 43.3 |
| Blue     | 83.1 |
| Yellow   | 86.4 |
|----------+------|
```

I would like to convert such a table to the following JSON format:

```
[
  ['Variable', 'Val'],
  ['Red', 43.3],
  ['Blue', 83.1],
  ['Yellow', 86.4]
]
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717483/howto-convert-org-mode-table-to-original-tabbed-format/17726489#17726489) describes a quick method to convert to CSV. Unfortunately, there is no `orgtbl-to-json` but if you look at the definitions of `orgtbl-to-csv` and `orgtbl-to-generic`, you might be able to come up with your own `orgtbl-to-json`.

Comment: have you included the column headers in the results string, on purpose?

Comment: @Saravana, yes, it's compliant with echarts' dataset format (https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/dataset/).

Comment: @NickD, thank you for your advice. As you can see, I almost found the solution. I was wondering if it was possible to add `"orgtbl-to-json"` to the formats list in the `org-table-export` function located in `org-table.el` from my init. I.e. without having to manually modify `org-table.el`, so when an Emacs update is installed, `"orgtbl-to-json"` is automatically added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of `orgtbl-to-json` along the lines of my comment. It's enough for your simple case and for the purposes of the Echart model you linked to:

```el
* Table

#+NAME: radar
|----------+------+---------+-------|
| Variable | Val1 |    Val2 | Val 3 |
|----------+------+---------+-------|
| Red      | 43.3 |   82.13 | 78.22 |
| Blue     | 83.1 |     9.6 |   9.8 |
| Yellow   | 86.4 | 133.465 |  27.5 |
|----------+------+---------+-------|

* Code

#+begin_src elisp :var x=radar :results drawer
  (defun orgtbl-to-json (table params)
    "Convert the `orgtbl-mode' TABLE to JSON material."
    (orgtbl-to-generic
     table
     (org-combine-plists '(
                           :sep ", "
                           :tstart "[" :tend "]"
                           :lstart "  [" :lend "],"
                           :llstart "  [" :llend "]"
                           :fmt (lambda (x)
                                  (let ((y (org-babel--string-to-number x)))
                                    (if y (format "%g" y)
                                      (format "\"%s\"c" x)))))
                         params)))
            
  (orgtbl-to-json x nil)
#+end_src


#+RESULTS:
:results:
[
  ["Variable", "Val1", "Val2", "Val 3"],
  ["Red", 43.3, 82.13, 78.22],
  ["Blue", 83.1, 9.6, 9.8],
  ["Yellow", 86.4, 133.465, 27.5]
]
:end:
```

EDIT: changed the single quotes to double quotes  - apparently, JSON string syntax uses double quotes only as delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

```
#+NAME: radar
|----------+------|
| Variable |  Val |
|----------+------|
| Red      | 43.3 |
| Blue     | 83.1 |
| Yellow   | 86.4 |
|----------+------|

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results value  :var table=radar
  (thread-last table                    ; (org-table-to-lisp)
               (seq-map
                (lambda (it)
                  (seq-into it 'vector)))
               json-encode)          
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: [["Variable","Val"],["Red",43.3],["Blue",83.1],["Yellow",86.4]]
```

---

This seems like a good starting point

```lisp
(thread-last
  "|----------+------|
| Variable |  Val |
|----------+------|
| Red      | 43.3 |
| Blue     | 83.1 |
| Yellow   | 86.4 |
|----------+------|
"
  org-table-to-lisp
  (seq-filter (lambda (it)
        (not (eq it 'hline))))
  (seq-map
   (lambda (it)
     (thread-last it
          (seq-map (lambda (it)
                 (or (org-babel--string-to-number it)
                 it)))
          (pcase--flip seq-into 'vector))))
  (pcase--flip seq-into 'vector)
  json-encode
  insert)
```

This uses `dash`

```lisp
(->>
 "|----------+------|
| Variable |  Val |
|----------+------|
| Red      | 43.3 |
| Blue     | 83.1 |
| Yellow   | 86.4 |
|----------+------|
"
 org-table-to-lisp
 (--filter (not (eq it 'hline)))
 (--map
  (->> it
       (--map (or (org-babel--string-to-number it)
                  it))
       (apply 'vector)))
 (apply 'vector)
 json-encode
 insert)
```

```js
[["Variable","Val"],["Red",43.3],["Blue",83.1],["Yellow",86.4]]
```

```js
[["Variable","Val"],["Red",43.3],["Blue",83.1],["Yellow",86.4]]
```

Comment: I get the error `error: (void-function thread-last)` on emacs `26.3`

Comment: (require 'subr-x)  (require 'seq)  (require 'pcase)

Comment: I updated  with a `dash` equivalent ...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additions on how to implement NickD's solution.

1. Put `orgtbl-to-json` function somewhere in your init.

```el
  (defun orgtbl-to-json (table params)
    "Convert the `orgtbl-mode' TABLE to JSON material."
    (orgtbl-to-generic
     table
     (org-combine-plists '(
               :sep ", "
                :tstart "[" :tend "]"
                :lstart "  [" :lend "],"
                :llstart "  [" :llend "]"
                :fmt (lambda (x)
                       (let ((y (org-babel--string-to-number x)))
                     (if y (format "%g" y)
                       (format "'%s'" x)))))
             params)))
```

2. set the `TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT` property to `orgtbl-to-json` :

```
:PROPERTIES:
:TABLE_EXPORT_FILE: ~/tmp/tmp.json
:TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT: orgtbl-to-json
:END:
|----------+------|
| Variable |  Val |
|----------+------|
| Red      | 43.3 |
| Blue     | 83.1 |
| Yellow   | 86.4 |
|----------+------|
```

3. Put the cursor within the table and do `M-x org-table-export`.

Comment: You are also missing commas. See my answer.

Comment: Indeed, thank you, your function is perfect. I just added some explanations on how I implemented it.

Comment: The fact that I cannot do a `json-read` the "desired output value" suggests that you either misunderstand `json` syntax or `json-read` is something wrong ... There is a reason why the result of my snippet is different from what you have requested, and the reason being that what you claim as `json` is not really `json`.  Btw, copy your `json` output to a file `demo.json`, turn on `flycheck-mode` and do `M-x flycheck-list-errors` and it will show `file.json     2   4 error           Expecting value (json-python-json)`.  Btw, I know nothing about `json` or `javascript`.

Comment: As mentioned in the question comments, the output format is called `Dataset` by Echarts documentation (https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/dataset/). As to whether it can be called JSON, I'm not 100% sure, but from my understanding, it seems to be compliant with JSON specifications (see https://www.json.org/json-en.html). If I'm wrong we can edit the references to JSON and replace them with references to Echart dataset.

Comment: The reason why I accepted NickD's answer, is not related to how the output looks. It is mainly because it provided a function that I can put in my init, which allows me to export tables easily (as I explained in my answer). Also, I prefer the use of `org-combine-plists`.